# Click on coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to click some coordinates of the webpage after it is being loaded (lets say x:250px && y:500px).

By native click i mean a real life event, like i use my mouse to click an image
or a link or whatever i want.

Is there anyway of doing it?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check what your browser support requirements are, but this should work for most modern browsers:

```
document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click();
```

Comment: This is a very valid answer... however it is still experimental https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint so just a warning ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers both. This javascript code does need any library to be loaded or its simple as that??? Also in x, y i can put the pixels as i want right? I mean the values!

Comment: You're welcome. There's no need to load plugins as it is based on a native Web API, and yes, x and y are numeric coordinates.

Comment: Yes, be careful with this highly experimental technology. IE only supports it from version 5.5 onwards. ahem

Comment: Before i tick your answer i will have a good look of it tomorrow. thanks a lot though for your time!!!

Comment: Is it able to click an iframe object? Because a simple image that im trying now, its clicking it perfectly